# graph-tool - k-shortest path - boost::coroutine was not found at compile-time

Tags: python-2.7, boost, ubuntu-14.04, graph-tool

I am trying to find the k shortest paths between two nodes in my directed graph. To this end I run the following snippet of code:

```
g = load_graph('graph.xml')
source = find_vertex(g,g.vp.xrn, '774123')
source = source[0]
target = find_vertex(g,g.vp.xrn,'636131')
target = target[0]
for path in all_shortest_paths(g,source,target):
  print path
```

This returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graph_tool/topology/__init__.py", line 1532, in all_shortest_paths
    _prop("v", g, all_preds_map))
RuntimeError: This functionality is not available because boost::coroutine was not found at compile-time
```

Any thoughts as to why that might be the case and how I could solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Debian, not in graph-tool. It has already been reported
and fixed: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=802509

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 14.04. I think it hasn't been fixed here yet?

Comment: I don't think so. An open bug report is here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/boost-defaults/+bug/1529289